# linq connection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, html-lists

This is my server name

```
server = LAPTOP-RED\SQLEXPRESS;
```

That is how my name is displayed on the login screen to SQL Server Management Studio. But I keep getting the following error about it when I'm trying to run the script

> Error 1 - Unrecognized escape sequence - 7

anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have mean't to enclose this in a string.

```
  server = "LAPTOP-RED\\SQLEXPRESS";
```

I would suggest trying this.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. My thought is that the solution Slade gave is correct, use a double backslash as one is seen as an escape character and will give indeed the error 'unrecognized escape seauence'.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a double backslash? So use `server = LAPTOP-RED\\SQLEXPRESS;`? If it is within a string in code, the single backslash will represent an escape character, and so it will try to escape the 'S' letter. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for more information on escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `server = @"LAPTOP-RED\SQLEXPRESS"` The @ takes care of the \ and the quote should solve your unescaped sequence thing.

Further, in case its the same machine you are developing on, consider "127.0.0.1" and "localhost" instead your address, if its a matter of network.

Harry